# Slider clashes with widgets and content placed after slider in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

put slider(fade effect),but when images change in the slider, the widgets which has to be placed just after slider in the homepage, clashes with slider,i guess there is a problem in margin top, coz when images changes,, the transaction time between one image to second image, during this time, the widgets, consider the margin-top from the menu bar,,but when image on the slider shown then it takes margin top from where slider starts,, plz look the code below:

put java script in html file in the body tag.. is it correct?

```
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></

script> 
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/scriptaculous.

js? 
load=effects"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

function ShowEffect(element){ 
new Effect.Appear(element, 
{duration:5, from:0, to:1.0}); 
} 
function FadeEffect(element)
{ 
new Effect.Fade(element, 
{duration:5, from:1.0, to:0}); 
} 
var i = 0; 
var path = new Array(); 
// LIST OF IMAGES path[0] = "/image_1.gif"; 
path[1] = "images/pic1.png"; 
path[2] = "images/pic2.jpg"; 
path[3] = "images/pic3.jpg"; 
path[4] = "images/pic4.jpg"; 
function swapImage_0() 
{ 
document.slide.src = path[i]; 
if(i < path.length -1) i++; else i =0; 
setTimeout("FadeEffect('hideshow')",4000); 
setTimeout("ShowEffect('hideshow')",5000); 
setTimeout("swapImage_0()",5000); 
} 
window.onload=swapImage_0; 

</script> 

<div id="hideshow"> 
<img height="260" name="slide" src="images/pic1.png" width="1350"/> 
</div> 

<div id="slider">

<a href="https://#" title="Learn More" class="slider1"  target="_blank"></a>

<a href="https://#" title="Learn More" Class="Slider2" target="_blank"></a>

<a href="https://#" title="Learn More" Class="Slider3" target="_blank"></a>

</div>
```

written css coding only for slider or you can call them widgets below:

```
#slider
{
height:240px;
width:1350px;
margin-top:400px;
background-color:#000000;
}



.slider1 {
background-image: url('images/slider1.png');
        height: 240px;
    width: 245px;
    margin: 0px 200px;
        padding-left:10px;
        float: left;
        -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
        z-index: 4;
}



.slider1:hover  {
        background-position: 245px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.slider2 {
background-image: url('images/slider2.png');


        height: 240px;
    width: 245px;
    margin-top:0px;
        margin-left:-100px;
        padding-left:9px;
        float: left;
        -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
        z-index: 4;
}


.slider2:hover  {
        background-position: 245px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}


.slider3 {
background-image: url('images/slider3.png');
        height: 240px;
    width: 245px;
    margin-top:0px;
        margin-left:85px;
        padding-left:9px;
        float: left;
        -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
        z-index: 4;
}

.slider3:hover  {
        background-position: 245px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

`position:absolute;`

to the sliders in CSS